# Updating Firebase Analytics Consent mode for Web app

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am unable to update Firebase analytics consent depending if user clicks either accept/reject button on a cookie banner.

Here's what I have attempted so far.

In my firebase-config file of my React/Vite web app, I have the following code:

```
import { getAnalytics, setConsent } from "firebase/analytics";


setConsent({
  analytics_storage: "denied",
  ad_storage: "denied"
});

//initialise Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export const auth = getAuth(app)
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app)
```

In my CookieBanner component I have two buttons, which either accept analytic cookies or reject:

```
import {setConsent} from "firebase/analytics";
  const handleAccept = () => {
    setConsent({
      analytics_storage: "granted",
      ad_storage: "granted"
    });
  }

  const handleReject = () => {
    setConsent({
      analytics_storage: "rejected",
      ad_storage: "rejected"
    });
  }
```

So, while analytics are initially denied when web app is initialised, I can not then switch to granted if the user clicks the accept button on the cookie banner

Is there a way to 'reset' the consent after app has initialized upon user interaction with cookie banner?